# Append (n) to file names (not using system.io.file) to ensure unique names

Tags: c#, loops, collections, zip

I have a class that holds the name of a file, and the data of a file:

```
public class FileMeta
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileData { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method that populates a collection of this class through an async download operation (**Files are not coming from a local file system**):

```
async Task<List<FileMeta>> ReturnFileData(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(async url => new
        {
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(url),
            FileData = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url),
        }));
        return results.Select(result => 
            new FileMeta
            {
                FileName = result.FileName, 
                FileData = result.FileData
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

I am going to feed this `List<FileMeta>` into a ZipFile creator, and the ZipFile like all File containers needs unique file names.

Readability is important, and I would like to be able to do the following:

```
file.txt => file.txt
file.txt => file(1).txt
file.txt => file(2).txt
```

There are a number of examples on how to do this within the file system, but not with a simple object collection. (Using `System.IO.File.Exists` for example)

What's the best way to loop through this collection of objects and return a unique set of file names?

**How far I've gotten**

```
private List<FileMeta> EnsureUniqueFileNames(IEnumerable<FileMeta> fileMetas)
{
    var returnList = new List<FileMeta>();
    foreach (var file in fileMetas)
    {
        while (DoesFileNameExist(file.FileName, returnList))
        {
             //Append (n) in sequence until match is not found?
        }
    }
    return returnList;
}

private bool DoesFileNameExist(string fileName, IEnumerable<FileMeta> fileMeta)
{
    var fileNames = fileMeta.Select(file => file.FileName).ToList();
    return fileNames.Contains(fileName);
}
```

Comment: What means "not using System.IO"? You are using `System.IO.Path`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good Point. I've seen a few examples that use methods tied into the file system, using things like `System.IO.File.Exists` that I cannot use here. I'll correct that. EDIT: Question edited to be more specific

Comment: Wesley how come you can not come up with your own unique naming convention using something unique for example `TimeStamp || DateTime || hhmmss+ fileName`

Comment: @clcto Hi again. Yes, the files being downloaded are unique in their folders, but we are accessing across folders. So if I grab files `http://file.com/folder1/sample.pdf` and `http://file.com/folder2/sample.pdf`, they are unique in their host location. But after downloading them into the `FileMeta` object, they are simply `sample.pdf` and we have a name conflict.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Readability. If someone is in a dropbox like experience and selects `sample.pdf` from two different folders, but the return value is `sample14123=-123=12312.pdf`, it violates usability spec.

Comment: perhaps you could write your own Rename routine

Comment: @DJKRAZE That's the idea, but I keep getting stuck in a loop where as the file names change I end up renaming more than once. Looking for some guidance on an effective renaming routine.

Comment: This should not have been closed. It is a clear and complete question. Just flagged it for attention.

Comment: well post the code where you are having the looping issues as you have stated I also voted to re-open but would need to see a bit more code as well in my opinion

Comment: the basic technique would be `string newName; do { index++; newName = string.Format("file({0}).txt", index); } while (NameIsInUse(newName));`

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, I deliberately left the implementation of NameIsInUse alone.  You could of course use a set, but to keep things simple, if it were possible, I would probably use File.Exists in the file system or, if we're talking about names in a zip file library, you could use its facility for querying files that have already been added, if there is such a facility.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Question edited with how far I've gotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following to increment the filenames:

```
private List<FileMeta> EnsureUniqueFileNames(IEnumerable<FileMeta> fileMetas)
{
    var returnedList = new List<FileMeta>();
    foreach (var file in fileMetas)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string originalFileName = file.FileName;
        while (returnedList.Any(fileMeta => fileMeta.FileName.Equals(file.FileName, 
                                            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            file.FileName = string.Format("{0}({1}){2}", fileNameOnly, count, extension);
            count++;
        }

        returnList.Add(file);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

As a side note, in your `ReturnFileData`, you're generating two lists, one of anonymous type and one of your actual `FileMeta` type. You can reduce the creation of the intermediate list. Actually, you don't need to `await` inside the method at all:

```
private Task<FileMeta[]> ReturnFileDataAsync(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    return Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(async url => new FileMeta
    {
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(url),
        FileData = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url),
    }));
}
```

I made the return type a `FileMeta[]` instead of a `List<FileMeta>`, as it is a fixed sized returning anyway, and reduces the need to call `ToList` on the returned array. I also added the `Async` postfix, to follow the TAP guidelines.

Comment: That's badass. Any danger in not wrapping the HttpClient in a using statement?

Comment: This is a quote from Glenn Block, currently working at Microsoft Azure (This is from Designing Evolvable Web API using ASP.NET): *Although HttpClient does indirectly implement the IDisposable interface, the standard usage of HttpClient is not to dispose of it after every request. The HttpClient object is intended to live for as long as your application needs to make HTTP requests.* If you see it causing any trouble down the road, you could always refactor.